# Monotone convergence theorem for recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_{n+1}= 1-\frac{1}{2}a_n$ and $a_1= 1$.  Does the sequence converge?  If so, what is the limit?

Attempt I tried to see if I could use the monotone convergence theorem, but after computing some of the terms in the sequence I found that the sequence was not monotone for many of the first terms. I am confident that the sequence tends to $\frac{2}{3}$ but I was wondering how to prove it converges. If the sequence is monotone after a finite number of terms, can the monotone convergence theorem be used to show convergence?If so how would I know after how many terms the sequence starts to become monotone? Also would this problem potentially be an application of showing that the sequence is cauchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n=a_n-\frac23$.  Clearly $a_n$ converges if and only if $b_n$ converges.

Now express $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$:

> \begin{eqnarray*}b_{n+1}&=&a_{n+1}-\frac23\\&=&1-\frac12a_n-\frac23\\&=&1-\frac12\left(b_n+\frac23\right)-\frac23\\&=&\frac12 b_n\end{eqnarray*}

> Thus $b_n=\frac1{2^{n-1}}b_1=\frac1{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: We should have a $-\frac12$ rather than $\frac12$ at the end.

Comment: I am really confused on this I have never seen this type of argument before.How does this imply the sequence converges to $2/3$? Why did you consider the sequence $b_n$?

Comment: You correctly identified that the limit would be $\frac23$.  To simplify things, I thought it would be easier to show that $a_n-\frac 23 \to 0$.  Here we have that $a_n-\frac23=\frac1{3\cdot2^{n-1}}\to0$.

Comment: Ok I think i understand this now, thank you.